# unbiased estimator

Tags: self-study, unbiased-estimator

Let $\hat p$ be the sample proportion of successes. Is $\hat p$ squared, an unbiased estimator for $p^2$?  [hint: For any rv $Y$, $E(Y^2)=V(Y)+[E(Y)^2]$]

If I replace $Y$ by $p$, I will have:
$E(p^2)$ not equal $p^2+p^2$
$\hat p$ square not equal $2 p^2$

However,  if I replace $V(Y)$ by $E(X^2)- [E(X)]^2$ then
 $$e(Y^2)= E(Y^2)- [E(Y)]^2 + [E(Y)^2] \\
        = E(Y^2)$$
  $$\hat p^2=  p^2$$

I am not sure which one is correct?

Comment: You write both $\hat{p}$ and $\hat{P}$ in some places. Is this a mistake or are they two different things? Just checking.

Comment: I tried to improve your formatting, but it is still a mess -- please review the changes to check if it is correct and correct your equations. Notice that this site uses $\TeX$ formatting. Is this a homework? If so, please check http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: No, check Jensen's inequality (which is strict when the r.v. is not degenerate): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality.

Answer (score 1):

No, $\hat p^2$ is not ubiased for $p^2$ because
$$
E(\hat p^2) = \operatorname{Var}\hat p + (E\hat p)^2 = \frac{p(1-p)}n + p^2.
$$
So the bias is equal to the unknown parameter $p(1-p)/n$.  Using the same method as above it is easily shown that $\hat p(1-\hat p)/(n-1)$ is an unbiased estimator of this bias, that is, $E\hat p(1-\hat p)/(n-1) = p(1-p)/n$.

Hence, subtracting this unbiased estimator of the bias from $\hat p^2$, the new estimator
$$
\hat p^2-\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n-1}
$$
becomes unbiased for $p^2$.